# Instagram like profile page with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I want to recreate an instagram like profile page. But want i'm trying to do now just doesnt cut it.
I want the page to be refreshable and the tabs on the bottom swipeable and also the items in the list inside the tabs to have swipeactions.
What i come up with up until now is

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        // This part is where my profile details are
        TopProfileSection()
        // here you can select which tab you want to see
        TabsView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        // These are the tabs
        VStack {
            if selectedTab == .posts {
                ForEach(userModel.posts) { post in
                    StreamPost(post: post)
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(userModel.upvotes) { post in
                    StreamPost(post: post)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which semi works but doesnt have the refreshable, swipeactions and swipe between tabs functionality.

Below is something i want but obviously doesnt work since an List doesnt allow me to have a section on top which is completely different from the list and i can add TabView inside.
Also the swipeActions wont work.

```swift
var body: some View {
    List {
        // This part is where my profile details are
        TopProfileSection()
        // here you can select which tab you want to see
        TabsView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        // These are the tabs
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(userModel.posts) { post in
                    StreamPost(post: post)
                        .swipeActions {
                            // Delete post
                        }
                }
            }
            .tag("posts")
            VStack {
                ForEach(userModel.upvotes) { post in
                    StreamPost(post: post)
                        .swipeActions {
                            // Delete post
                        }
                }
            }
            .tag("upvotes")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
    .refreshable {
        // code to refresh the profile page
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some tips into the right direction. UIKit i also fine.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do the same thing and am running into similar problems.

Comment: Nope sorry, abandoned the idea.

Comment: @andredewaard, have you managed to solve it? If yes, could you please point me in the right direction?